# Django Dynamic Scraper Project does not run on windows even though it works on Linux

Tags: python, django, web-scraping, scraper, scraperwiki

I am trying to make a project in dynamic django scraper. I have tested it on linux and it runs properly. When I try to run the command: syndb i get this error

/*********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************/
python : WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\Python27\l
ib\site-packages\django_dynamic_scraper-0.3.0-py2.7.egg\dynamic_scraper\migrations/*.*'
At line:1 char:1
+ python manage.py syncdb
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (WindowsError: [...migrations/*.*':String) [],
   RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

/*********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************/
The admin server runs properly with the command python manage.py runserver

Kindly guide me how i can remove this error

Answer (score 0):

Step # 1
download django-dynamic-scraper-0.3.0-py2.7.tar.gz file
Step # 2
Unzip it and change the name of the folder to:
django-dynamic-scraper-0.3.0-py2.7.egg
Step # 3
paste the folder into C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages